# What is the last stable version of php 5.4

Tags: php, version, php-5.4

Im currently working on php 5.3.13, and im thinking to upgrade my system for woocommerce im wondering what is the stable version in php 5.4? Is it 5.4.44?

Comment: http://nz2.php.net/downloads.php is the manual that hard to read?

Comment: PHP 5.4 is outdated. The current stable version of PHP is **5.6.26** and 7.0.11.

Comment: because if i use higher version to my system it might deprecated some other functions im just moving for just one step of my current version @CharlotteDunois

Comment: I hate it when Google goes down. What? It's still up? Really?

Comment: I already look on that site, and nothing says about the stable version for php 5.4. @nogad

Comment: Oh poor you, you want to upgrade but you dont wanna deal with deprecated functions.

Comment: there is no such thing as a stable 5.4. there are 2 stable versions of php  5.6.26 and 7.0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LAST stable version of PHP 5.4 was 5.4.45, released at 09/2015.

You can get this info or download the files [here](https://secure.php.net/releases/).

The two CURRENT stable versions are PHP 7.0.11 and 5.6.26.